# Avoid loading libraries on multiple run of R script

Tags: r, scala, rscript, rserve

I need to run (*several times*) my R script (*script.R*), which basically looks like this:

```
library(myLib)
cmd = commandArgs(TRUE)
args=myLib::parse.cmd(cmd)
myLib::exec(args)
```

`myLib` is my own package, which load some dependencies (*car, minpack.lm, plyr, ggplot2*). The time required for loading libraries is comparable with the time of `myLib::exec`, so I'm looking for a method which helps me not to load them every time I call `Rscript script.R`

I know about `Rserve`, but it looks like a little bit overkill, though it could do exactly what I need. Is there any other solutions?

P.S: I call `script.R` from *JVM* using *Scala*.

Comment: Looking at ?library in R,  a package will only be loaded if it is not already loaded. But if a new R instance is started every time you ".. call Rscript script.R" then mylib will have to be loaded on each call. Ps: What else does mylib do? Is loading other packages its only job?

Comment: And the wrapping Scala code that is looping and calling this several times is not trivially converted to R so that the loop could be inside the script? Or could you accumulate all the sets of `args` over the loop, and have an R script that runs once and loops over all the sets of args?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly:

- on startup you need to load your libraries
- if you call repeatedly *and start repeatedly* you repeatedly load the libraries
- you already mentioned a stateful solution ([Rserve](http://rforge.net/Rserve)) which allows you start it once *but connect and eval* multiple times

so I think you answered your question.

Otherwise, I enjoy [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) and have shown how it [starts faster than either R or Rscript](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2014/09/02#littler-faster-at-doing-nothing) -- but the fastest approach is simply not to restart.

Answer (score 0):

I tried littlr, seems amazing, but don't want to work on R v4.0.
Rserve seems cool but like you pointed out it seems to be an overkill.

I end up limiting the import to the functions I need.
For example:

```
library(dplyr, include.only = c("select", "mutate","group_by", "summarise", "filter" , "%>%", "row_number", 'left_join', 'rename') )
```